# SAS Match-Merge statement creating duplicate cases

Tags: merge, sas, duplicates

I am attempting to merge 2 datasets with the common identifier `investigation_id`. Each case should have an identical match of the ID. The first 2 steps are used to apply a numeric format to the ID as it imports as character sometimes. Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
data data1;
    set data1(rename=(investigation_id=new_id));
    investigation_id=put(new_id, 12.);
    drop new_id;
    run;
data data2 ;
    set data2 (rename=(investigation_id=new_id));
    investigation_id=put(new_id, 12.);
    drop new_id;
    run;
proc sort data =data1 nodupkey;
by investigation_id
;
run;
proc sort data = data2 nodupkey;
    by investigation_id
;
run;
data final;
    merge data2 data1;
    by investigation_id;
    run;
```

When I run that, it produces double the expected observations, instead of matching by the ID.

Comment: Your code is converting numbers to strings which is totally different than your stated reason for making the conversion.  Numbers are easier to match (at least integers) as strings of digits might have different numbers of leading spaces or leading zeros and so not match exactly.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to work with that has this issue in SAS datalines or csv format? It's hard to tell without some data, but I suspect that the `put()` statement on `new_id` may not be doing what is expected.

Comment: Are they extra observations because of mismatches?  Or because one (or both) of the datasets have repeated values of the BY variable?

Comment: @Tom thank you! So the extra observations are because the datasets each have an observation of the BY variable (1 has 3 more observations than the other). I modified the code to say "input" instead of "put", and used the BEST12. format. With those changes, the cases all matched correctly. Thanks so much for your tips!

Comment: @StuSztukowski thanks for your tips! Using yours and Tom's clues, I was able to solve the problem.

Comment: Note that BEST is a FORMAT and for the INPUT() function you need to use an INFORMAT. You just need to use the normal `w.` informat.  You can use a longer width than the string you are giving to the INPUT() function.  So use the maximum width of 32.  `investigation_id=input(new_id, 32.);`

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion for dealing with "Sometimes character sometimes numeric" is to use `cats`.  `put` or `input` are a bit inconsistent; most likely in your case you're getting differently aligned results (so    `123` vs `123`   ).  They also will put warnings in your logs when you have the "right" type (so if you try to `input` a numeric).

`CATS` is nice because it guarantees you character out, gets rid of spaces (left-aligns), and doesn't generate anything in your log.  Best of course is to get your input data consistent, but if that's not practical, this can be.

```
data data1;
    set data1(rename=(investigation_id=new_id));
    investigation_id=cats(new_id);
    drop new_id;
    run;
data data2 ;
    set data2 (rename=(investigation_id=new_id));
    investigation_id=cats(new_id);
    drop new_id;
    run;
proc sort data =data1 nodupkey;
by investigation_id
;
run;
proc sort data = data2 nodupkey;
    by investigation_id
;
run;
data final;
    merge data2 data1;
    by investigation_id;
    run;
```